# Uphill, downhill, what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I run uphill faster than downhill
> People don't touch me, that's chill
> I tend to destroy more than create
> But I can be used to make something great
> I am loud and I eat, but I have no mouth
> I travel around, west, east, north, or south
> People hate me, yet love me as well
> The smaller, the better, that's what they tell

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fire

> I run uphill faster than downhill

> Fire travels faster going upwards because hot air is pushed upward and cold air is consequently pulled in from underneath (so, more easily from the downhill side), which pushes the fire uphill.

> People don't touch me, that's chill

> Usually, people don't touch fire. That's chill, because if they did touch fire, it wouldn't be very chill anymore.

> I tend to destroy more than create

> Fire does create, but it mostly just destroys, specifically, whatever it's burning.

> But I can be used to make something great

> Food, I guess. Also glass. And various other things.

> I am loud and I eat, but I have no mouth

> No mouth. But fire is quite loud, and I suppose it "eats" fuel (and oxygen).

> I travel around, west, east, north, or south

> Well, fire spreads indiscriminately of direction.

> People hate me, yet love me as well

> Forest fires, building fires, any unintentional fires really suck. But we also couldn't live without it to warm us, help us travel, cook food, etc.

> The smaller, the better, that's what they tell

> Smaller fires are better, in general; large fires get out of control and then cause damage and death.

Comment: perfect. makes sense.